# Attaching Tempfile with ActiveStorage error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

I can't attach a JSON Tempfile to a model using Active Storage in a **service object**. This is easily replicable:

Model:

```
class ServiceRequest < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :data_file
```

Process:

```
temp_file = Tempfile.new([SecureRandom.uuid, '.json'])

@service_request.data_file.attach(temp_file)
```

Error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved (Failed to save the new associated data_file_attachment.)
```

I have `data_file` defined as `string` on the `ServiceRequest` model. Not sure what the problem might be here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can’t pass a Tempfile object alone to `#attach`. You must pass a Hash containing an open `:io`, a `:filename`, and a `:content_type`:

```
@service_request.data_file.attach(io: temp_file, filename: "data.json", content_type: "application/json")
```

See [the docs](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Attached/One.html#method-i-attach) for `#attached` for more information on the arguments it accepts.

Comment: thank you. Any idea on how to get its URL after it is uploaded? .url method from the docs does not seem to be working.

Comment: Please ask a new question with more details about the problem you’re having.